# Python exe runtime error: Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I'm running Anaconda 64-bit, with Python 3.5.5, on Linux Mint Xfce 18.3, 64-bit. I want to use PyInstaller to create an executable. After struggling through the PyInstaller install (not trivial), I ran `pyinstaller test_build.py`, where test_built.py consists solely of

```
print("Hello, world!")
```

I don't get any warnings or errors that are unexpected (overwrites folder if I've done it before, of course). I `cd` into `./dist/test_build` and run `./test_build`, and I get the following errors:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't find module 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007fe95dc36700 (most recent call first):
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Any ideas? Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: [this github issue](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3219) looks related

Comment: @AzatIbrakov: I did see that github issue. I'm a little puzzled as to why a virtual environment should be necessary. It doesn't sound like a root cause solution. What's really going on, here?